# Duplicate objects based on prop list

Tags: ramda.js

I have a list of objects such this one:

```
var original = [
  {
    prop1: 1,
    prop2: 2,
    tags: ["tag1", "tag2"]
  },
  {
    prop1: 3,
    prop2: 4,
    tags: ["tag1", "tag3", "tag4"]
  },
  {
    prop1: 5,
    prop2: 6,
    tags: ["tag4"]
  }
]
```

I want to duplicate the objects based on tags in order to finally have one object for every tag (also duplicated ones) using ramda.js.

```
var parsed = [
  {
    prop1: 1,
    prop2: 2,
    tags: ["tag1"]
  },
  {
    prop1: 1,
    prop2: 2,
    tags: ["tag2"]
  },
  {
    prop1: 3,
    prop2: 4,
    tags: ["tag1"]
  },
  {
    prop1: 3,
    prop2: 4,
    tags: ["tag3"]
  },
  {
    prop1: 3,
    prop2: 4,
    tags: ["tag4"]
  },
  {
    prop1: 5,
    prop2: 6,
    tags: ["tag4"]
  }
]
```

I tried with this function but I think there is some better solution

```
var f = (a,b) => R.evolve({tags: () => a}, b)
R.unnest(
  R.map((v) =>
    R.zipWith(f, v.tags, R.repeat(v, v.tags.length))
  )(original)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
const dup = pipe(
  map(obj => map(tag => merge(obj, {tags: [tag]}), obj.tags)),
  flatten
);
```

Or, perhaps more readably, like this:

```
const spread = obj => map(
  tag => merge(obj, {tags: [tag]}
), obj.tags);

const dup = pipe(
  map(spread),
  flatten
);
```

While this probably could be made points-free with enough effort, it would likely be much uglier.

You can see this in action on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?var%20original%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20prop1%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20prop2%3A%202%2C%0A%20%20%20%20tags%3A%20%5B%22tag1%22%2C%20%22tag2%22%5D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20prop1%3A%203%2C%0A%20%20%20%20prop2%3A%204%2C%0A%20%20%20%20tags%3A%20%5B%22tag1%22%2C%20%22tag3%22%2C%20%22tag4%22%5D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20prop1%3A%205%2C%0A%20%20%20%20prop2%3A%206%2C%0A%20%20%20%20tags%3A%20%5B%22tag4%22%5D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%5D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20dup%20%3D%20pipe%28%0A%20%20map%28obj%20%3D%3E%20map%28tag%20%3D%3E%20merge%28obj%2C%20%7Btags%3A%20%5Btag%5D%7D%29%2C%20obj.tags%29%29%2C%0A%20%20flatten%0A%29%3B%0A%0Adup%28original%29%3B%0A)**.